# Obtain WebApplicationContext in Spring 3.1 Junit test

Tags: spring, junit

Due to custom framework dependencies, I cannot upgrade to Spring 3.2+. I'm stuck on 3.1.x. I am trying to obtain a WebApplicationContext in a Spring JUnit test like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/context.xml")
public class WebIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;
```

This, as expected, does not load a WebApplicationContext.

I realize that in Spring 3.2 or later I could just use `@WebAppConfiguration` to tell Spring that I want a web context provided, but how can I achieve this with my dependency constraints?

Comment: you cannot. At least not using the normal spring classes, you would have to write your own and construct an `XmlWebApplicationContext` yourself and use a `MockServletContext` to mock the web dependencies (and probably some more). It would be easier to force an upgrade imho.

Answer (score 2):

I too am stuck on 3.1, at least until I can get enough testing around this code to upgrade - but can't test enough until I can get a working WebApplicationContext...

It isn't too hard to construct the WebApplicationContext, only a whole morning of trial and error.

So, for a test like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = MyLoader.class,
    locations =
    {
    "file:WEB-INF/springcontexts/spring-security-common.xml",
    "file:WEB-INF/springcontexts/webapp-common.xml"
})
public class LoginIntegrationTest {
```

you can define

```
public class MyLoader implements ContextLoader {

    @Override
    public String[] processLocations(Class<?> clazz, String... locations) {
        return locations;
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationContext loadContext(String... locations) throws Exception {
        XmlWebApplicationContext result = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        MockServletContext servletContext = new MockServletContext("target/webapp", new FileSystemResourceLoader());
        result.setServletContext(servletContext);
        result.setServletConfig(new MockServletConfig(servletContext));
        result.setConfigLocations(locations);
        result.refresh();
        return result;
    }
}
```

You'll need to change the paths to match your own, or pass them around somehow.